# How to pass Json objects from js to java in android phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I believe that there is a way to pass the json objects from JS to java using phonegap plugin. If anybody knows please help me on this. Thanks in advance buddies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a java class like this

```
public class MyJavaScriptInterface 
{

    Activity parentActivity;
    MyJavaScriptInterface(Activity activity){
             parentActivity = activity;
    }

    public void processData(String jsonString){
        /* your processing logic */

    }
```

in your activity

```
MyWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "MyHandler");

in your html page 



<a href="#" data-transition="slide" onClick="window.MyHandler.processData("+jsonString+")">

Change this with your page code (html Page)
```

Comment: by sending JSON data like this I'm getting this error
`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", source: file:///android_asset/'`

my code formatted like this with including JSON data 

`<img src="http://45.55.46.149/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/android-smart-text-selection-350x175.jpg" onClick='window.JavaScriptInterface.showImages("[{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}]");' />`